# Timestamp comparison to delete when mysql timestamp > 20 minutes

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, comparison, sql-delete

I want to do something which is not complicated but I do not manage to succeed even after I tried a lot of things....

First of all, I have a database mysql with a row of timestamp type. I insert into it elements with a date like this:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
$req =mysql_query("INSERT INTO my_table (id, departement, voie, date,message)
    VALUES ('', '$departement_token', '$voie_token','$date' , '$message_token')");
```

The result of this code line is a date element like this : `2012-07-19 20:18:17`

I want to delete all elements with a `date > current date + 20 minutes` and I do not succeed...

I tried this:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE  DATE_SUB(date,INTERVAL 20 MINUTE) ORDER BY date");
```

And this:

```
$req=mysql_query("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE date >= TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE,-20,NOW())
                  ORDER BY date");
```

And this:

```
$timePlus20min = time() + 1200;
//et on compare les deux dates
$req = mysql_query(
    "DELETE FROM my_table WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) >= '$timePlus20min' ORDER BY date");
```

But none of this works. Could you help me please, I think it's not too difficult but I'm out of ideas...

Comment: It might help if you show us the structure of your table. Well, and maybe the errors you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
$req=mysql_query("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE date <= ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(date("H"), date("i")-20, date("s"), date("m"), date("d"), date("Y")));
```

Bonne chance à toi / Good luck

Comment: Try to dump the request and look if the generated date is really "now-20mn", if it is, the query seems to be good :(

Comment: This solution work perfectly ! THANKS VERY MUCH ! But i shall adapt a little bit the code like this (maybe a parenthesis error..) :            $reqDate= date("Y-m-d H:i:s", mktime(date("H"), date("i")-20, date("s"), date("m"), date("d"), date("Y")));
$req=mysql_query("DELETE FROM rmytable WHERE date <= '$reqDate'");

Answer (score 3):

```
$period=date('Y-m-d H:i:s',time()-(60*60*6)); // 6 hour before

"SELECT * FROM limitlessisa WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(REG) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$period')";

REG // timestamp row name
```

This is working. 6 hours before listing data

Comment: $delete=mysql_query("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE TIME < NOW()-10800"); // 10800 = 3*60*60 3 hour before
More beautiful code

Answer (score 2):

In all your queries you forgot the `WHERE` keyword so they are syntactically wrong. Also, the `ORDER BY` statement has no effect as you are not executing a `SELECT` query. There is no result that could be ordered. Instead, a single table `DELETE` query returns [a count of the number of deleted rows](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html).

```sql
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE date >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 20 MINUTE);
```

As I do not know your table structure, I tried this query with the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `datetest` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

Comment: No worries, but there is more missing, you are not comparing `date` to the `DATE_SUB` result.

Comment: What does it say? It works for me. It deletes all entries with a `date` LATER THAN 20 minutes from now.

Comment: Im new in phpmyadmin too, how can i retreived for you the table structur to show  ?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mytable` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `departement` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    `voie` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `message` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=151 ;

Comment: Created your table, ran my query => works. Do you get an error or does it delete the wrong rows?

Comment: Nothing happen. I do not whant to removed my table, because i have some data in, is there a other way instead of delete ?

Comment: You can always do a `SELECT` with the same `WHERE` clause to see what would be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) > 60 * 60 * 20 + UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
```

Comment: *"Try this:"* is a [subpar answer decoration](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help10). Instead please add a slim explanation of *what* your code does, *why* you'd recommend it, or *how* you came to the conclusion.